Expected Trials for Dual-Condition Set Partitioning
If we have a set of 200 elements that are repeatedly randomized in order, then split into two groups: one group contains 80% of the elements, and the other group contains the remaining 20%. This process is repeated until all elements meet the following two conditions:
80% Split Condition: Each element must be assigned to the 80% group multiple times such that it appears at least once in each of 10 distinct bins. Specifically, the 80% group is split into 10 equally sized bins during every trial, and an element assigned to this group must be placed in each bin at least once over the course of multiple trials.
Number of Bins in 80% Split: 10
20% Split Condition: Each element must be assigned to the 20% group at least once.
Number of Elements in 20% Group: 40
Basically this process continues until:
Every element has appeared in each of the 10 bins in the 80% split at least once.
Every element has appeared in the 20% split at least once.
The question is to find the expected number of trials (or splits) needed for all 200 elements to meet both the 80% split condition and the 20% split condition.
Note that a trial refers to selecting all 20% and 80% at once, from the randomized 200 elements.
I think this problem might be similar to the Coupon collector's problem, but i have ran a montecarlo simulation and my analytic solution did not match my theoretical one at all.

Just to be clear:  you should say whether the "bins" are equally sized or whether the sizes differ.

I would start with a simpler problem:  Suppose all the elements were independent.  That is, in each trial each element gets assigned one of the $11$ possible outcomes with whatever probabilities, independent of all the others.  Now you are just looking for the expected maximum time to completion.  For a large number of elements (maybe $200$ is enough?  Not sure) I would think this was close.

@lulu, i updated the question. They are equal sized, yes.
Are you suggesting to calculate 11 * H_11 and then generalize for maximum time to completion?

I don't recognize that notation.  If you are referring to the Coupon Collector problem, then, yes.  You need to work out the expected length of the longest path to completion.  I don't expect a pleasant answer.
